# Setting distro and machine in image recipe?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I'm trying to make Yocto configuration usable out-of-the-box.

The standard procedure is to modify `local.conf` to set `DISTRO` and `MACHINE`, however I find this inconvenient for configurations with multiple machines and images tailored to specific machine.

I tried the following:

Leave `local.conf` as is (ie. `DISTRO ?= "poky"` and `MACHINE ??= "qemux86-64"`).

I have following image configurations:

- `distro-image-default` which sets all distro configuration and `DISTRO = "distro"`. It should be usable with multiple different machines.
- `machine-image-default` which sets machine related stuff and `MACHINE = "machine"`. This should be usable with multiple distros.
- `distro-image-machine` which only `require`s two previous images

The idea here is to be able to mix and match different distros with different machines without having to remember to set `local.conf` accordingly.

Setting distro in image doesn't work at all, I suppose because `?=` being used in `local.conf`. I probably can live with it.
However, setting the machine in image produces the following error:

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'packagegroup-cross-canadian-machine'
NOTE: Runtime target 'packagegroup-cross-canadian-machine' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['packagegroup-cross-canadian-machine']
ERROR: Required build target 'distro-image-machine' has no buildable providers.
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['distro-image-machine', 'packagegroup-cross-canadian-machine']
```

Setting the same machine in `local.conf` builds the image as expected.

I suppose I have 2 questions about this:

1. Why does setting machine in image configuration break the build process?
2. Is there some easier way to achieve multiple build configurations without modifying `local.conf`?

Comment: Somewhat tangential: have you seen the [kas](https://github.com/siemens/kas) project? It makes Yocto image configuration a breeze (relatively speaking, compared to the barefoot manual config) - one of its main benefits (beside others) is that it takes care of local.conf content after a mostly one-time configuration.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @skandigraun's comment, you can use `KAS` project for your need.

I don't know exactly what can fit your case, but I will put this answer for anyone wants to know about `KAS` and a quick example in the future.

It is really hard to do it manually, because this can lead to multiple ideas that can or cannot suite your case, for example:

- Use `repo` utility to sync all layers automatically and then create a shell script that gets an env var or something else to setup Yocto `TEMPLATECONF`.
- Use `KAS` as follows:

You need to install it first, check [kas-docs](https://kas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html)
Assuming you have a project folder called `yocto-kas-configs`, you can follow the following example:

```
yocto-kas-configs
|-- kas/
    |-- common/
    |   |-- oe.yml
    |   |-- layers.yml
    |   `-- conf.yml
    |
    |-- machines/
    |   |-- machine1.yml
    |   `-- machine2.yml
    |
    |-- images/
    |   |-- common.yml
    |   |-- custom-image1.yml
    |   `-- custom-image2.yml
    |
    |-- custom-image1-machine1.yml
    `-- ...
```

- `oe.yml`: Contains OE and Poky

```yaml
header:
  version: 14

repos:
  poky:
    url: https://git.yoctoproject.org/git/poky
    path: layers/poky
    branch: <BRANCH>
    layers:
      meta:
      meta-poky:
      meta-yocto-bsp:

  meta-openembedded:
    url: https://git.openembedded.org/meta-openembedded
    path: layers/meta-openembedded
    branch: <BRANCH>
    layers:
      meta-oe:
      meta-networking:
      meta-python:
      meta-gnome:
      meta-initramfs:
      meta-multimedia:
      meta-webserver:
      meta-filesystems:
      meta-perl:
```

- `config.yml`: Contains your `local.conf` and `bblayers.conf` common configs:

```yaml
header:
  version: 14

bblayers_conf_header:
  standard: |
    POKY_BBLAYERS_CONF_VERSION = "2"
    BBPATH = "${TOPDIR}"
    BBFILES ?= ""

local_conf_header:
  default: |
    # -- Default local.conf from meta-poky/conf/local.conf.sample -- #
    EXTRA_IMAGE_FEATURES ?= "debug-tweaks"
    USER_CLASSES ?= "buildstats"
    PATCHRESOLVE = "noop"
    BB_DISKMON_DIRS ??= "\
        STOPTASKS,${TMPDIR},1G,100K \
        STOPTASKS,${DL_DIR},1G,100K \
        STOPTASKS,${SSTATE_DIR},1G,100K \
        STOPTASKS,/tmp,100M,100K \
        HALT,${TMPDIR},100M,1K \
        HALT,${DL_DIR},100M,1K \
        HALT,${SSTATE_DIR},100M,1K \
        HALT,/tmp,10M,1K"
    PACKAGECONFIG:append:pn-qemu-system-native = " sdl"
    PACKAGECONFIG:append:pn-nativesdk-qemu = " sdl"
```

- `layers.conf`: Contains your custom common layers like `meta-qt6` or something else.
- `machine1.yml`: Contains BSP layer of `machine1`, example:

```yaml
header:
  version: 14

machine: machine1

repos:
  meta-machine1:
    url: <URL>
    path: layers/meta-machine1
    branch: <BRANCH>
```

- `common.yml`: Contains custom `includes` for all images:

```yaml
header:
  version: 14
  includes:
    - kas/common/oe.yml
    - kas/common/layers.yml
    - kas/common/conf.yml

# You can define here common DISTRO if you have one
```

- `custom-image1.yml`:

```yaml
header:
  version: 14
  includes:
    - kas/images/common.yml

target: custom-image
```

- `custom-image1-machine1.yml`: Image `custom-image` with `MACHINE = "machine1"`:

```yaml
header:
  version: 14
  includes:
    - kas/images/custom-image1.yml
    - kas/machines/machine1.yml
```

Now you can run:

```bash
git clone <URL>/yocto-kas-configs
kas build yocto-kas-configs/kas/custom-image1-machine1.yml
```

This will create this structure for you, (assuming you cloned in a folder called `yocto`):

```
`-- yocto
    |-- yocto-kas-configs  <== Your project
    |-- layers             <== All specified repos
    `-- build              <== The actial build folder
```

Comment: This definitely looks interesting, I'll look into it, thanks!